# Add comma between DB rows when creating a string using concatenation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, string-concatenation

i am creating a large string from all rows inside a database.

This works fine, however i am having issues when using the string as an array as the ending of each database row does not end with a comma so i am getting a joining between the last and first word.

How can i change this:

```
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // concatenate all the tags into one string
    $tags .= $row['tags'];
  }
```

So that each of the $row['tags'] has a comma after it?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate your tags and comma at each iteration

```
$tags .= $row['tags'] . ',';
```

To remove the last comma you just need `substr()`

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // concatenate all the tags into one string
    $tags .= $row['tags'].',';
}

$tags = substr($tags,0,-1);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :) Knew it was something like this but couldnt get the syntax right. I am using this for counting words. So getting a count of how many times each word appears in this string. Would a trailing comma cause any issues? I cant see it my logic but i might be wrong.

Comment: I would need to see how you count times words appair, comma shouldn't be a problem though

Comment: thanks for the edit. Decided to remove the last comma just incase :)

Comment: @Dagon last comma is now removed

Comment: Yeah that might be another option

Answer (score 5):

I would go with:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   // concatenate all the tags into one string
   $tags[] = $row['tags'];
}
$tagsString = implode(",", $tags);
```

Comment: more memory used and slower than @Fabio's

Comment: clean and straight forward, as long as you don't start dealing with more `$tags[]` than can fit in memory.  PHP is not the right layer to handle more data than this can reasonably manage.

Comment: I like what Fabio did, I used to do it myself, but I always have to clean that last `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$atags = array_column($row, 'tags');
$tags = implode(',',$atags);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's PDO, Luke

```
$sql = "SELECT tags FROM table WHERE something = ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute([$condition]);
$tags = implode(",",$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0));
```

It's Mysql, Luke

```
$sql = "SELECT group_concat(tags) FROM table WHERE something = ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute([$condition]);
$tags = $stm->fetcnColumn();
```